# MySQL ORDER BY logic

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

What's the logic?

```
SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2... 
ORDER BY field1, [field2...] [ASC [DESC]]
```

So if I have `ORDER BY field1, field2` :

(Please let me know if i'm wrong) it will sort results by `field1` and if `field1` has the same values in a couple rows (`field1[235]=field1[236]`) only in then `ORDER BY field2` kicks in. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed.

That is how it works.

But why do I see so many of these questions here on SO? What happened to experimenting, trying stuff out, playing, etc?

Comment: No way! That was a stab in the dark. I tried to google it and couldn't find any decent explanation

Comment: Seriously? You didn't google `mysql order by` and got a zillion pages saying exactly this?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Seriously! Haha Smuggy comment for smuggy answer ) i didn't research it, just briefly looked. Right now when i know what to look for i found it in a fifth link.